# How to integrate BatteryModule with any host of Anna Forster in WSN?

Tags: omnet++

I would like to integrate [Battery module](http://www.inf.usi.ch/postdoc/foerster/downloads/BatteryModuleMF_11-02-2009.zip) of [Anna Forster](http://www.inf.usi.ch/postdoc/foerster/downloads.html) with a wireless sensor host or node.

How do I do it ?